# jQuery.post(), Status Code: 301, не срабатывает POST запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть данный код

```
  const requestData = {
            'key': 'key',
            'email': apiRequest.email,
        };

        const userData = await request(apiRequest.apigetuserdata, requestData);


async function request(apiUrl, requestData) {
        const resultRequest = await jQuery.post(apiUrl, requestData);
        return resultRequest;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я отправляю POST, я получаю ошибку 301 и делается автоматически GET запрос
Как это исправить, чтобы срабатывал POST

Comment: У вас вроде post на картинке.

Comment: POST отправляется и я получаю 301, снизу где красным, там уже GET запрос 
ПОчему для POST возвращает 301?

Comment: как минимум смотреть на сервере надо, куда запрос отправляете

Comment: Запрос идет правильно, если я сменю на GET(в API) и отпралю с фронта GET -> все работает, с POSt почему то 301